# Issues with heat map in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to draw a heat map in matplotlib in two ways:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(rtl, zs, bins=(128, 128))
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.clf()
plt.xscale('log')

plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
plt.show()
```

The second way is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

hb = ax.hexbin(rtl, zs, gridsize=50)
ax.axis([min(rtl), max(rtl), min(zs), max(zs)])
plt.show()
```

But for the same data, I am getting really different plots. I am not understanding what is going on here.

[plot1](https://imagebin.ca/v/3YHcqeoi87O9)
[plot2](https://imagebin.ca/v/3YHdD8YftGir)

Answer (score 1):

IF You look carefully at the pictures than both graphs appear to be the same. As one is in log scale while one is normal graph.

Comment: the data along x axis was converted to log scale before drawing both of the graphs. For the first one, if I do not set plt.xscale('log'), then it is not scaled properly. But I do not see how they are the same plot, the second one looks like rotated along the axis